# Add decimal value formate for fild in angulare

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, mat

I Want To Set Number Format Decimal Like 0.00 In Material Filed

**My Code Is This**

```
 <div class="col-md-2 col-12 pl-0 ">
   <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
     <input matInput [(ngModel)]="txtOCAmtD"   placeholder="XX.XX"  style="text-align: right;">
   </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

I Add Placeholder But It's Not Work.
I Want To Every Value In .00 Decimal If It's .01 or .10 Both Are Required.
Any One Tell Me How Can Do It.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use something like this:

```
<input value="{{ exampleNumber | number : '1.2-2' }}"></input>
```

`'1.2-2'` means `'minIntDigits.minDecimalDigits-maxDecimalDigits'`

- 1 digit or more will be shown in front of decimal point
- At least 2 digits will be shown after decimal point
- But no more than 2 digits will be shown after decimal point

**Edit:**
If the above does not work with MatInput you can also add a directive and add it to your html. Kindly refer to
https://stackblitz.com/edit/limit-two-digit-decimal-place?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: it is not accept in matInput, if i use only input that it work fine but with matInput not work.